# What is the reward for defeating all 17 Cyberpsychos?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

After traversing every region in Night City and engaging in a series of difficult fights I've defeated and incapacitated all 17 Cyberpsychos. Afterwards, I was called to Regina's location and she congratulated me for vanquishing the psychos without outright killing them - and then nothing happened. The 'Psycho Killer' side gig finished but I didn't seem to get a reward, and Regina didn't mention any bonus payout.

Am I missing something? Will she contact me later to offer a payout when her research has concluded? I anticipated a reward for defeating all of the Cyberpsychos but nothing seems to have happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this in new to patch 1.23 (I had to wait for "Where the Bodies Hit the Floor" to be fixed), you get a couple pieces of legendary clothing: Trauma Team Armor Weave Tactical Vest and a Decadencia Verde Tactical Armor-Weave Pants. They are easy to miss, on the floor of her office in a flat case.

Comment: It’s been a while since I’ve played Cyberpunk. To confirm, this is a quest reward - not just a loot box that happens to be near Regina?

Comment: @PausePause, To confirm, I just finished the mission. I did it without killing a single cyber psycho and I did indeed get the legendary gear upon completion.

Answer (score 5):

There is no in game reward beyond the eddies you make while completing these missions for Regina. There is also no follow up mission once you have completed all of them like there are with some of the missions in game. You will get between 1000 and 3000 eddies per mission you complete.

Once all of the cyber psycho sighting missions have been completed you will earn the achievement "I am the law".

Answer (score 3):

You got handed some Eddies. It’s easy to miss when that happens.

As with most missions, the cash is the only direct reward.

Comment: Do you know approximately how many Eddies I was awarded? I noticed that my wallet amount didn’t seem to change, or it maybe changed very, very little. Likewise, the wikia article for Psycho Killer votes that a reward may be bugged.

Comment: Psycho Killer claims* don’t know why it autocorrected to votes

Answer (score 2):

If you do not kill one single cyberpsycho after finishing the 17th one it will prompt you to "wait until Ragina contacts you." Just skip 24hrs and she will call. She will tell you to meet up with her. Go to her location and ask about the situation. She will thank you and the chest with the legendary orange marker will be unlocked. You should get two legendary class clothing items from the chest. Maybe you glithed out and they fixed this later IDK.